# I am getting permission error while trying to convert the list of texts in the picture to a list in python

Tags: python, opencv, python-tesseract

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import ast



pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR'

img=cv2.imread("number_1.jpg")


img=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
new_array=[]
arr=pytesseract.pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
try :
    arr = ast.literal_eval(arr)

except:
    arr=arr.split("\n")
    arr =list(filter(None, arr))

    for i in arr:
        i=i.split(",")
        for j in i:
            j =int(j)
            new_array.append(j)

    arr=new_array

    

cv2.imshow("result",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I am getting a permission error when trying to convert the list of texts in the picture to a list in python. I don't have to do this test this way, but it happened when I tried it yesterday, but it didn't work today.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ayano\OneDrive\Masaüstü\tesseract_detect_text\main.py", line 14, in <module>
    arr=pytesseract.pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
  File "C:\Users\ayano\OneDrive\Masaüstü\tesseract_detect_text\lab_interpreter\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 423, in image_to_string
    return {
  File "C:\Users\ayano\OneDrive\Masaüstü\tesseract_detect_text\lab_interpreter\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 426, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
  File "C:\Users\ayano\OneDrive\Masaüstü\tesseract_detect_text\lab_interpreter\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 288, in run_and_get_output
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ayano\OneDrive\Masaüstü\tesseract_detect_text\lab_interpreter\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 255, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
  File "C:\Users\ayano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 969, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\ayano\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1438, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Erişim engellendi
```

Comment: (1) Shown code is syntactically incorrect. Better copy and paste it from your code editor directly. (2) Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question. (3) Generally it is better to use absolute paths and to use raw strings (prefixed with `r`) for such paths to ensure that backslashes are processed correctly.

Comment: ı edited it, can you check ?

Comment: I doubt that `r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR'` is really the path to the executable but only to the directory containing it.

Comment: I tried changing it but still didn't work.pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

Comment: Explain "didn't work". If there was an error, show the full traceback of it as properly formatted text in the question, too.

Comment: I don't see a comment about the answer to the question. Please don't write unnecessary text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I extracted the 22mb file size named "eng.traineddata" to an external folder .that is to the folder named tesseract-ocr.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).